# In Excel application-level C# add-in, set Data Source without wizard

Tags: excel, vsto, datasource, add-in

I am trying to write an add-in that will allow a user to connect to a SQL database and draw the data from a table into Excel. (This is the simplest explanation, but not the entire explanation of the necessary functionality.) I found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668212%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

and it works nicely. However, my question is this: how could I create the data source (mentioned in "Creating a Data Source" in the above link) programmatically?

For example, I would like the user (via the Excel add-in) to be able to enter the server name, database name and table name, and then create a specific dataset, tableAdapter and bindingsource. I don't want to "hardcode" (or use a wizard to achieve) it in the add-in prior to kicking-off Excel.

And I think there is something where one can just import data into Excel. That is not what I am looking for. There are reasons for wanting to use an add-in.

Any help / references will be much appreciated!
:-)

Comment: Okay, could you give me a reference to where I could find more information about the coding option? I don't know how to create for instance, a SOMENAMEdataset.xsd as the wizard seems to accomplish.